# Can a query be optimized so that running analyze isn't necessary?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, innodb

I have a Drupal site with a MySQL db (all innodb tables) that "crashes" (read: runs slowly) every once in awhile. The server hosting is cloud based and the "crashing" happens when the database is moved to a new a container.  A query that joins about 10 tables and returns a single row starts running extremely slowly (1 minute) after the move and everything grinds to a halt. Normally the query executes very quickly (less than .1 seconds) and is not an issue.

It was determined that the move causes the "crash" because the MySQL server loses its "analyze" information - that's stored in memory and it gets lost when the database is moved.

It's not currently possible to automatically run analyze after the move. The hosting company is suggesting that the query be re-written so that analyze isn't necessary. I wanted to ask the community if this makes sense and how I might approach rewriting it.

---

Here is info copied from the OP's pastebin:

> Query_time: 0.052842 Lock_time: 0.000530 Rows_sent: 1 Rows_examined: 61031

```
SELECT node__field_last_sl_play.field_last_sl_play_value AS node__field_last_sl_play_field_last_sl_play_value, node_field_data.nid AS nid, node_field_data_node__field_album.nid AS node_field_data_node__field_album_nid, node_field_data_node__field_artist.nid AS node_field_data_node__field_artist_nid, node_field_data_node__field_event.nid AS node_field_data_node__field_event_nid, votingapi_result_node_field_data.id AS votingapi_result_node_field_data_id, node_field_data_node__field_lifestyle.nid AS node_field_data_node__field_lifestyle_nid
FROM
node_field_data node_field_data
LEFT JOIN node__field_album node__field_album ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_album.entity_id AND node__field_album.deleted = '0' AND (node__field_album.langcode = node_field_data.langcode OR node__field_album.bundle = 'track')
LEFT JOIN node_field_data node_field_data_node__field_album ON node__field_album.field_album_target_id = node_field_data_node__field_album.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_artist node_field_data_node__field_album__node__field_artist ON node_field_data_node__field_album.nid = node_field_data_node__field_album__node__field_artist.entity_id AND node_field_data_node__field_album__node__field_artist.deleted = '0' AND (node_field_data_node__field_album__node__field_artist.langcode = node_field_data_node__field_album.langcode OR node_field_data_node__field_album__node__field_artist.bundle = 'album')
LEFT JOIN node_field_data node_field_data_node__field_artist ON node_field_data_node__field_album__node__field_artist.field_artist_target_id = node_field_data_node__field_artist.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_event node__field_event ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_event.entity_id AND node__field_event.deleted = '0' AND (node__field_event.langcode = node_field_data.langcode OR node__field_event.bundle = 'track')
LEFT JOIN node_field_data node_field_data_node__field_event ON node__field_event.field_event_target_id = node_field_data_node__field_event.nid
LEFT JOIN votingapi_result votingapi_result_node_field_data ON node_field_data.nid = votingapi_result_node_field_data.entity_id AND (votingapi_result_node_field_data.entity_type = 'node' AND votingapi_result_node_field_data.function = 'vote_sum' AND votingapi_result_node_field_data.type = 'vote')
LEFT JOIN node__field_lifestyle node__field_lifestyle ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_lifestyle.entity_id AND node__field_lifestyle.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN node_field_data node_field_data_node__field_lifestyle ON node__field_lifestyle.field_lifestyle_target_id = node_field_data_node__field_lifestyle.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_last_sl_play node__field_last_sl_play ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_last_sl_play.entity_id AND node__field_last_sl_play.deleted = '0'
WHERE (node_field_data.status = '1') AND (node_field_data.type IN ('track'))
ORDER BY node__field_last_sl_play_field_last_sl_play_value DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;
```

EXPLAIN report for this query:

```
EXPLAIN
1   SIMPLE  node_field_data index_merge node_field__type__target_id,node__status_type   node_field__type__target_id,node__status_type   34,35   
    NULL
    2288    Using intersect(node_field__type__target_id,node__status_type); Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_album   ref PRIMARY,bundle  PRIMARY 5   dbname.node_field_data.nid,const    1   Using where 
1   SIMPLE  node_field_data_node__field_album   ref PRIMARY,node__id__default_langcode__langcode    PRIMARY 4   dbname.node__field_album.field_album_target_id  1   Using where; Using index    
1   SIMPLE  node_field_data_node__field_album__node__field_artist   ref PRIMARY,bundle  PRIMARY 5   dbname.node_field_data_node__field_album.nid,const  1   Using where 
1   SIMPLE  node_field_data_node__field_artist  ref PRIMARY,node__id__default_langcode__langcode    PRIMARY 4   dbname.node_field_data_node__field_album__node__field_artist.field_artist_target_id 1   Using where; Using index    
1   SIMPLE  node__field_event   ref PRIMARY,bundle  PRIMARY 5   dbname.node_field_data.nid,const    1   Using where 
1   SIMPLE  node_field_data_node__field_event   ref PRIMARY,node__id__default_langcode__langcode    PRIMARY 4   dbname.node__field_event.field_event_target_id  1   Using where; Using index    
1   SIMPLE  votingapi_result_node_field_data    ref vote_result_field__type__target_id,vote_result_field__entity_id__target_id  vote_result_field__entity_id__target_id 5   dbname.node_field_data.nid  1   Using where 
1   SIMPLE  node__field_lifestyle   ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 5   dbname.node_field_data.nid,const    1       
1   SIMPLE  node_field_data_node__field_lifestyle   ref PRIMARY,node__id__default_langcode__langcode    PRIMARY 4   dbname.node__field_lifestyle.field_lifestyle_target_id  1   Using where; Using index    
1   SIMPLE  node__field_last_sl_play    ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 5   dbname.node_field_data.nid,const    1
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `node_field_data` (
 `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `vid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `type` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL COMMENT 'The ID of the target entity.',
 `langcode` varchar(12) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The ID of the target entity.',
 `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `changed` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `promote` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `sticky` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `revision_translation_affected` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `default_langcode` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `rh_action` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `rh_redirect` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `rh_redirect_response` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`nid`,`langcode`),
 KEY `node__id__default_langcode__langcode` (`nid`,`default_langcode`,`langcode`),
 KEY `node__vid` (`vid`),
 KEY `node_field__type__target_id` (`type`),
 KEY `node_field__created` (`created`),
 KEY `node_field__changed` (`changed`),
 KEY `node__frontpage` (`promote`,`status`,`sticky`,`created`),
 KEY `node__status_type` (`status`,`type`,`nid`),
 KEY `node__title_type` (`title`(191),`type`(4)),
 KEY `node_field__uid__target_id` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='The data table for node entities.'
```

Comment: Do you think there might be a reason why Google, AWS, Oracle and Azure recommend using their hosted database service rather than running a transactional database on a virtual machine/service?

Comment: BTW a query cannot be executed until it is parsed and an execution plan created.

Comment: @symcbean are you saying that analyze has to be run before the query is executed? If so, why wouldn't that be happening automatically? The weird thing is this has been fine for 2 years and now suddenly things have gone wrong. FWIW this is a reputable hosting company that uses Google for its containerization.

Comment: Does it swap?  If so, you have tuned things too high.  Let's see my.cnf and the size of the VM.

Comment: @RickJames Does the "variables" from phpmyadmin work? https://pastebin.com/jqLBnHU0

Comment: The innodb stats for a table should be refreshed the first time the table is opened after a restart, in exactly the same way that ANALYZE TABLE does. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-statistics-estimation.html

Comment: You could also rely on persistent table stats: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-persistent-stats.html

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin - looks like persistent table stats should be happening since "innodb stats persistent" and "innodb stats auto recalc" are set to ON.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the query that is exhibiting the nasty slowdown.

Comment: How much RAM?..

Comment: Using `FULLTEXT` indexing?

Comment: @codesmith: Your use of the term "crash" here is very circumspect. The actions of the "analyze" command persist in the storage, not in memory. The only things in memory are cached data and execution plans.

Comment: Here's the query and explain and table structure for one of the tables: https://pastebin.com/cUCvakJ3

Comment: RAM -- It's a container so I think it's variable.
FULLTEXT indexing - not sure
By "crash" I mean everything slows down so that the db becomes unusable. Query takes 60 secs to execute. Interestingly, in the query I just posted it says about 60k rows were examined when things are running normally/quickly. When things are "crashed" that number jumps to 45 million.

Comment: To other engineers, "crash" conventionally means that a process _exited_. It does not mean it ran successfully, but slower than normal.

Comment: I copied your pastebin into your question above. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask makes it clear that you should include relevant information **in your question**, not in a pastebin.

Comment: *"
Do you think there might be a reason why Google, AWS, Oracle and Azure recommend using their hosted database service rather than running a transactional database on a virtual machine/service?"*   Besides earning money as main reason? @symcbean ...

Comment: @codesmith  Since you and your HOSTING company know that a MOVE to another container REQUIRES ANALYZE to complete the process, why is this not a PART of the process?  Sure would save you and all their customers a lot of grief and wasted time for this pantheon hosted site.

Comment: @codesmith  Using SSH, could you post to pastebin.com (because you are about at your limit for this question) the TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES: ?  The SGV posted a few hours ago are inconsistent in the use of column separators and the values have comma edited values.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I don't have any control over what the hosting company does. My goal here is to see if this can be solved by changing the query. Here's the pastebin https://pastebin.com/01G20DQi - thanks for any pointers!

Comment: @codesmith Thanks for the SGS and SGV from SSH output.  Much more readable.  Can you post the 'code' used to move a database to a new container?  I take it this is done by the hosting company to achieve their goals and you only find out after their part of the action is completed (when response time becomes unreasonable).  If you want to Skype TALK, view my profile, Network profile and get in touch, please.

Comment: Wilson Hauck - I don't have access to that code. I take it you're not seeing anything that is out of norms or possible improvements as far the query goes?
@symcbean - Aren't the execution plans the product of running analyze? Not clear on what the "actions" of analyze being stored means. Is the info that's needed loaded into memory when mysql is started up? Perhaps a race condition is happening where the db is handling queries but hasn't finished loading the "analyze" info it has stored?

Comment: When could we Skype TALK?

Comment: @codesmith  Your question to smycbean "Aren't the execution plans the product of running analyze?" No, in MySQL execution plans are the result of the OPTIMIZER.  Search for 'mysql analyze tutorial' for several ways of knowing where ANALYZE fits within MySQL.  You also asked about a race condition.  Yours is not a race condition, you had a 'missing indexes' condition until ANALYZE completed updating the indexes for the table that was moved by your hosting organization.

Answer (score 0):

codesmith, There is NOTHING wrong with your query.  It runs in .1 second when your tables have reasonable indexes rather than 1 minute.  Since you and your HOSTING company know that a MOVE to another container REQUIRES ANALYZE to complete the process, why is this not a PART of their process?  "FWIW this is a reputable hosting company that uses Google for its containerization."  Try to convince the hosting company to the extra mile and ANALYZE every table - just after their 'move' to avoid this discovery in the next few days (or weeks)  when the 'abnormally long running query' shows up.  I would still like to Skype TALK with you when time permits.